# How can I used Regex to access this data

Tags: regex, diaspora

This is the data in the JS file:

```
    [{\"value\":16633,\"name\":\"fdgdfgdf@joindiaspora.com\"},{\"value\":16910,\"name\":\"jamesw@wk3.org\"},{\"value\":16911,\"name\":\"sdasfasf@joindiaspora.com\"}]" ),
```

and I want to output it in a 2d array something like:

> value    name,
>
> 16633    fdgdfgdf@joindiaspora.com,
>
> 16910    jamesw@wk3.org,
>
> 16911    sdasfasf@joindiaspora.com

here is my code so far:

```
$.ajax
({  
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://wk3.org/conversations/new',
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var matches;
        var Ragex = /\\"value\\":\\"(.*)\\",\\"name\\":\\"(.*)\\"},/g           //need to sort out the REGEX so it goes through each name and ID seeing if it equals ID
        while ((matches = Ragex.exec(data)) !== null)
        {
            console.log(matches);
        }
    }

});
```

which outputs:

```
["\"value\":\"16633\",\"name\":\"fdgdfgdf@joindiaspora.com\"},…"},{\"value\":\"16910\",\"name\":\"jamesw@wk3.org\"},", "16633\",\"name\":\"fdgdfgdf@joindiaspora.com\"},{\"value\":\…"name\":\"sdasfasf@joindiaspora.com\"},{\"value\":\"16910", "jamesw@wk3.org", index: 92, input: "<script>↵  //<![CDATA[↵    $(document).ready(funct…it" value="Send" />↵</div>↵</form>↵</div>↵</div>↵"]
```

Comment: Can you show us the result you're getting from the web service?  Before you've manipulated it, that is.

Comment: do you want me to screen shot the console log?

Comment: change the two occurrences of `(.*)` to `([^"]*)`, as long as you don't have escaped double quotes in values, that should match what you want.

Comment: it says it cant be deleted as it has answers, I have put my answer at the bottom

Comment: First make sure your code is correct. There is minor spelling mistake for word "Ragex". It should be "Regex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax
({  
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://wk3.org/conversations/new',
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var matches;
        var name;
        var regex = /{\\"value\\":\\"([^"]*)\\",\\"name\\":\\"([^"]*)\\"}/g         //need to sort out the REGEX so it goes through each name and ID seeing if it equals ID
        while ((matches = regex.exec(data)) !== null)
        {
            console.log(matches);
            var name = matches[2];
            if(name == ID)
            {
                result = matches[1];
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("FAIL");
                //this sends a message to me only
                //need to add error trapping saying recipient cannot be found!
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you wish to capture ? in `\":\"?\"`, right ?

I am not familiar to diaspora.

In python, pattern `(\":\").(\")` should make it

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean, I am new to REGEX and im struggling to output it like I want above.

Comment: I wrote the pattern for capturing what you want (python). then, you must do your diaspora code for outputing the result